# What is error code 30000 from REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, journeybuilder

I was using SFMC REST API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm) for firing an event to my journey. I just noticed that there was a few error records happened.

ERROR:

```
{"message":"Value for attribute(s) exceeds max length","errorcode":30000,"documentation":""}
```

DATA:

```
E-Mail: xxxxxxxx@gmail.com, 
ID: x, 
FName: xxxxxxx, 
LName: xxxxxxx, 
Mobile: xxxxxxxxxx, 
ID-Card: xxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
Grade: xxxx, 
Color: xxxxxxxx/ xxxxxxxxxxx, 
DealerName: xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 1995  xxxxxxxxxx xxxx, 
Logo: xxxxxx, 
RegisterCode: xxxxxxxx
```

Is there a limit length of sending REST API? 
Where do I find this specific detail?
How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Just add maximum length of a field in Data Extension